# How to work out device type in titanium (iOS)

Tags: ios, titanium-mobile

I am trying to work out the device type in titanium for iOS i.e. if the user is using iphone 4, 5, 6, or 6 + 
I have used:

`Titanium.platform.model` but it just returns simulator (I guess because I am running it in a simulator), what is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get the actual model, but you can derive it from other info:

- iPhone 6+ would have `@3x` for `Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor`
- iPhone 5/6 would have `@2x` and could be further split up via `Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight`
- iPhone 4 and older would have `@1x`

In Alloy, you could create globals with this in `alloy.js` - e.g.:

```
Alloy.Globals.iPhone6P = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor === '@3x';
...
```

Comment: Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight is "568" for iphone 6 plus and iphone 6 and when I do Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor it is "2" for iphone 6 and iphone 6+. How can I differentiate it?

Comment: Solved this, there is a bug with older titanium versions where the height is always 568 and the width is ALWAYS 320, essentially making it a fixed size. To resolve this, copy and paste all of your files into a new titanium mobile alloy project. Be warned all old styling will go out of position.

Comment: Just found a bug, when I build the app on my phone the width is 320

Comment: @bobo2000 if you don't include the launch images for iPhone 6 or 6+ then iOS will automatically start in compatibility mode (letterbox or upscaled) and report the dimensions of that mode. So please check if you have all the required assets.

Comment: Yep that was the issue. I have kept it in compatibility mode for the time being.